# Android views memory footprint

Tags: android, memory-management, view

One of the major challenges while building android applications is managing memory footprint of app with limit so as to avoid crashes.

How much memory does each of the following `View` in Android occupy (independent of the content contained within)?

- `TextView`
- `ImageView`
- `WebView`
- `VideoView`
- `TextureView`
- ..other commonly used ones

Comment: this would be interesting to know but I think you would have to create really tons of views to crash your app just with those

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a very easy way to find out, in Android Studio (2.2.3 atm) open the Android Monitor window (n. 6) and within that select "Monitors" tab. There should be 4 sections (Memory, CPU, Network and GPU), and in the Memory section you should see some icons, the one to the right of the garbage truck should be "Dump Java Heap". Clicking that one will take a snapshot of the memory used by your app so that you can inspect it object by object and see how much memory is being used by each one of them.

Answer (score -1):

The memory allocated for each of them can vary insanely depending on the content, for instance the memory footprint of a WebView rendering the google search page would be nowhere close to that of a graphic HTML5 Canvas game. 
When it comes to the memory footprint of a View it is not how much memory is allocated for them that matters, rather it is how you handle your Views that does.
for instance Views hold a HardReference to the Activity in which the were created, so keeping a View referenced even after it's Activity was destroyed/recreated for configurational changes(let's assume), this would keep the previous Activity in memory and thus causing a memory leak. 
do watch [DO NOT LEAK VIEWS (Android Performance Patterns Season 3 ep6)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkbHeFHn8JY)